# Use map to create object and also on a condition

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array like this -

```
details = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'xyz'
    type: 1
    coun1: 5,
    count2: 6
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'abc'
    type: 2
    coun1: 4,
    count2: 3
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'def'
    type: 1
    coun1: 2,
    count2: 8
  }
]
```

If I do

```
updatedInfo = details.map(data = > {
  if (type == 1) {
    return {
      totalCount = data.count1 + data.count2
    }
  }
});
```

I am getting totalCount for type 1, but for others it shouldn't return anything but it is returning undefined.

Comment: It [really isn't difficult](https://beautifier.io/) to provide formatted code. Please consider it for your next post.

Comment: Should this `if (type == 1) ` really be this: `if (data.type === 1) `? If not, what is `type`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to add another property (`total_count`) to those objects of type==1, you can `filter()`, then `map()` and use the `spread {...}` syntax to add the new property

```
updatedInfo = details.filter(e => e.type === 1)
          .map(e => ({ ...e, total_count: (e.coun1 + e.count2)}))
```

```js
details = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'xyz',
    type: 1,
    coun1: 5,
    count2: 6
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'abc',
    type: 2,
    coun1: 4,
    count2: 3
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'def',
    type: 1,
    coun1: 2,
    count2: 8
  }
]

updatedInfo = details.filter(e => e.type === 1).map(e => ({ ...e,
  total_count: (e.coun1 + e.count2)
}))

console.log(updatedInfo)
```

Comment: Here I don't want all the other parameters. I just want the total_count and id. That is the reason I am using map.

Answer (score 1):

Replace ‘type’ with ‘data.type’

Answer (score 1):

There is a 1:1 mapping between input and output arrays with `Array.map`.

Your mapping function implicitly returns `undefined` if `type == 1` is `false` (actually should be `data.type == 1` as highlighted in other answers/comments). These are the `undefined` values in your output array.

You should filter, then map:

```
details.filter((data) => d.type === 1)
       .map((data) => data.count1 + data.count2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.map()` will run on all the elements and created a transformed array of the same length. You are only returning an element for a specific condition. For other default values it will be `undefined`. (Functions that do not return anything return undefined)

Also, `type==1` should not be work. You probably meant `data.type == 1`.

In any case, to get data only for `type == 1`, you need to `.filter()` out some elements first, and then use `.map()` to convert into your required result.

```
updatedInfo = details.filter(data = > {
 return data.type == 1;
}).map(x => {
   return { 'totalCount' : x.count1 + x.count2 }
});
```